# Split string with regular expression - objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex, split

I'm quite new to regular expression and I'm trying to learn it.

Here's my string:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt)
```

And I want to split it up to an array which looks like this:

```
@[@"Mozzila", @"4.0", @"compatible", @"MSIE 5.0", @"Windows NT", @"DigExt"];
```

This is the code I tried:

```
NSString *expression = @"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt)";
NSRegularExpression *testExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"([a-zA-Z]+)/([1-9.]+) \(([a-z]+); ([a-zA-Z .]+); ([a-zA-Z ]+); ([a-zA-Z]+)\)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
                                                                                options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [testExpression matchesInString:expression 
                                           options:0 
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [expression length])];
NSLog(@"%@",matches);
```

Also tried with:

```
[testExpression enumerateMatchesInString:expression
                                 options:0
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [expression length])
                              usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                                  NSLog(@"Value: %@", [expression substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]]);
                              }];
```

And also:

```
NSRegularExpression *testExpression = [NSRegularExpression
                                       regularExpressionWithPattern: @"(\w+)/(\w+) \((\w+);([\w .]+); ([\w ]+); (\w+)\)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                       error:nil];
```

But the log is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: on a side note, have you tried Reggy for testing your RegEx

Comment: It looks like you're trying to match the entire string with your regex. That's not what you want - you want your regex to identy the individual parts that to pull out of the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSString *expression = @"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt)";
NSRegularExpression *testExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.+)/([0-9\\.]+) \\(([^)]*).*"
                                                                                options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [testExpression matchesInString:expression
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [expression length])];
NSLog(@"%@",matches);

NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];
[matches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    for (int i = 1; i< [obj numberOfRanges]; ++i) {
        NSRange range = [obj rangeAtIndex:i];

        NSString *string = [expression substringWithRange:range];
        if ([string rangeOfString:@";"].location == NSNotFound) {
            [array addObject: string];
        } else {
            NSArray *a = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            for (NSString *s  in a) {
                [array addObject: [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];
            }

        }

    }
}];
```

`array` contains

```
<__NSArrayM 0x10010d540>(
Mozilla,
4.0,
compatible,
MSIE 5.0,
Windows NT,
DigExt
)
```

---

```
@"(.+)/([0-9\\.]+) \\(([^)]*).*"
  ^__^                           capture group 1
       ^_________^               capture group 2
                     ^           the char (
                      ^_____^    capture group 3
```

- Capture group 1 captures all printable chars till /.
- Capture group 2 captures all numbers and dots. we must escape the dot with `\\`, as otherwise it would again stand for any character.
- `\\(` says that a `(` will follow, but as we dont enclose it it our capture groups, we just dont care much for it.
- Capture group 3 `([^)]*)` says "anything printable but not `)`

Now we iterate over the capture groups with their ranges. we start at index 1, as index 0 will give the range of the complete expression

---

```
([1-9.]+)
```

this will not match `0` and the points stands for any printable character. you want

```
([0-9\\.]+)
```

Comment: Nope, still nothing. And I get a warning: unknown escape sequence '\\)'

Comment: Nope, and "Unknown exit sequence '\w'

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: [«Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.»](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: I added some explanations.

Answer (score 3):

```
  NSString *yourStr= @"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt)";

    NSArray *arrComponents = [yourStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/;()"]];
```

Comment: This will also produce the strings @" MSIE 5.0", @" Windows NT" and @" DigExt", all with an initial space

Answer (score 0):

I think better you should use below like this:-

```
NSString *yourString  = @"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT; DigExt)";
NSArray *array = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
NSlog(@"%@",array);
```

Like that whatever format you want to `split` you can just pass special character into that `componentsSeparatedByString` method